# Making selection with ModelBuilder using parameter

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, select

[image: Model-works up thru summary stats]I am using ArcMap 10.5.

I am trying to calculate the volume and area of a pit using ModelBuilder (I need a non-python solution). The pit will by preselection have the largest volume of any pits in the selected area, but not necessary the largest area (the no-change area will usually be larger). I can isolate the volume of the pit in the CutFill raster using Summary Statistics (yielding a max_volume value).

I am having trouble configuring a selection to use the max_volume result of Summary Statistics to select the entry in the CutFill attribute table with that value. I cannot figure out how to get Select to recognize the max_volume variable for an SQL query. I tried %max_volume%, but no go.

In the attached image, I would be happy using either the extract by attribute or select tool to select from the cut_fill_raster raster using the max_volume value from Max_volume_value. Question marks indicate where I am adrift.

Comment: just taking a swing at it, but have you considered adding a field and using field calculator so that you can work with a differently named field? probably not the answer you're looking for, but it's a possible workaround.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful - combined with a Get Field Value allowed me to perform the workaround. But what I am really interested is what would seem to be a very simple and common task - select by a parameter.